# Comparing datetimes in php not working

Tags: php

I have the following session value

```
$_SESSION["time"] = 2015-01-09 23:57:38 (example value)
```

And the variable **$test**

```
$test = time() - (60 * 1); (1 minute)
$test  = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$test);
```

What I want to do is check whether 1 minute as passed. To do this I have the following code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["time"]) && (strtotime($_SESSION["time"]) > $test)){
   echo "first";
 }else{
   echo "second";
}
```

Independently to which logic comparison I use (< or >), after a minute a page refresh still echoes the same... any idea on why? I'm finding this really strange...

Comment: So you storing the first time in the session variable then compare it with the current time in `$test`? In that case you condition is wrong in terms of `$test` will always be `>=` to the one stored in session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparision should be like

```
($_SESSION["time"] > $test)
```

PHP now will compare two string values instead of integer (return value from `strtotime` call) and string (return value from `date` call)

Comment: What do you mean *now*? I think my script worked before, did something change?

Comment: You are converting `$_SESSION["time"]` string value to UNIX timestamp  integer value and comparing it with `$test` string value which actual doest not work

Answer (score 0):

What he actually wants is...

```
strtotime($_SESSION["time"]) > strtotime($test))
```